# Syntax error on token "=", Expression expected after this token

Tags: массивы, java

Начал изучать java. Составил такой код:

```
int a[];
int b[];
int c[];
b = c = [3];
System.out.print(b + " " + c);
```

Появилась ошибка в предпоследней строчке:

```
Syntax error on token "=", Expression expected after this token
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Блин, вот зачем так извращаться? Неужели нельзя создать двумерный массив, ну или хотя бы в каждом массиве сразу указать его размерность? Ведь второе не только упростит код для восприятия, но и сократит его =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

или так

```
    int b[];
    int c[];
    b = c = new int [3];
```

создаем 2а массива Б и С, а потом их инициализируем выделив им размер 3 ячейки. Причем Б и С будут ссылками на один массив.

Comment: > выделив им размер 4 ячейки

@Gorets, вы хотели сказать "3 ячейки"?

Comment: из трех. Вы указываете размер. А индексы будут 0, 1, 2

Comment: точно из трех

Answer (score 2):

> b = c = [3];
>
> Как исправить?

А что вы хотя бы сделать пытались?

Предположу, что создать 2 массива по 1му элементу равному 3.

```
int b[] = new int[] { 3 };
int c[] = new int[] { 3 };
System.out.print(b[0] + " " + c[0]);
```